# How do I delete a new page created by another user who hasn't checked it in?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, check-out, duplicate

A user has created an aspx page, but not checked it in.

Only discovered when trying to create the page again (with same name) - it won't let us, because the page already exists.

Is there any way to view/access pages that have been created, but left checked out, by people who have since left?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your document library, do the following:

1. Settings - Document Library Settings
2. Under Permissions and Management click on `Manage files which have no checked in version`
3. From this page you can select files and choose to take ownership, after which you should see them in views and can delete them